# How to search against a specific field/s, and not every field related to an element?

Tags: search

I have the below. I want to only show results that contain the query in the the username or fullName attributes.

Because currently if I search for say Tom the search results will return users without a username or full name containing the query Tom, but will show a person if the email contains it. I don't want this as emails are not publicly shown and therefore may cause confusion to the user searching.

How would I exclude email from the search criteria or only allow searching from the username or fullName attribute?

The same happens when searching entries - how do I narrow the search to only use the title field for example otherwise the search results can be too broad which is bad for UX.

```
{% set users = craft.users()
    .search(query)
    .group('creatives')
    .all() %}

{% if users|length %}
    <p>{{users|length }} results:</p>

    <ul>
        {% for user in users %}
           <li><a href="/people/{{ user.username }}">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Your search for {{ query }} didn&#39t return any users.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just limit your search to those specific user fields.

It should go something like:

```
{% set users = craft.users()
    .search('fullName:' ~ query ~ ' OR username:' ~ query)
    .group('creatives')
    .all() %}
```

More info on searching here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/searching.html#supported-syntaxes

**Top tip:** You can test your search query directly in the search bar within Craft's admin. e.g. See if `fullName:Tom OR username:Tom` pulls the intended results.

Comment: Awesome that seem's to work perfectly! I had something similar but it didnt work as expected first time around.

Appreciate it